# Displaying JSON data in Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, json

I am having an issue displaying json data. I have searched and found many examples, but for some reason I get the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error, because "var object = notes.data;" comes back as undefined.

**Why is object undefined? From everything I can see I am doing it right.**

**My json that is returned.**

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "NumberOfAnswers":25,
         "Answer":"51-89 Percent of all items in section are <b>IN STOCK<\/b>",
         "Percent":54.35
      },
      {  
         "NumberOfAnswers":21,
         "Answer":"90-100 Percent of all items in section are <b>IN STOCK<\/b>",
         "Percent":45.65
      }
   ]
}
```

**And here is the function to display it. (With some debugging code as well)**

```
 function format(notes) {
     console.log(notes); //this displays the json
     var object = notes.data;
     console.log(object);
     var i;
     for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
         var Result = object[i];
         var Answer = Result.Answer;
         console.log(Answer)
     }

  }
```

Here is the ajax function:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: '/rmsicorp/clientsite/pacingModal/surveyajax2.php',
     success: function(result) {
         if (row.child.isShown()) {
             row.child.hide();
             tr.removeClass('shown');
             detailsrows.splice(RowID, 1);
         } else {
             row.child(format(result)).show();
             tr.addClass('shown');
             if (RowID === -1) {
                 detailsrows.push(tr.attr('id'));
             }

         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: 1) Your function closing bracket `}` is missing in your question. 2) you declare twice the `var i`

Comment: are you sure that `notes` is a raw javascript object ? and not JSON (string) ? then you need `JSON.parse(notes)` before.

Comment: Its not unclouded, I have other code that is under the pasted code. Ill fix it here though. yes, i declare I twice, but that is not making notes.data undefined.

Comment: @Hacketo the Notes coming into the function is a json return from jquery ajax function. I am using php to return with json encode.

Comment: @Hanoncs so `notes` is not of type `string` ? to ensure try `console.log(typeof notes)`

Comment: Just tried to reproduce the error, but everything looks ok => http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/gLvfLxzb/

Comment: Can you try to `console.log` your `result` inside the `else` of your `success` handler and add it to your question please ? Are you sure it's the same as you posted ?

Comment: @Magicprog.fr that is weird, I posted the ajax function that fills format()

Comment: Do I need a datatype? or will javascript recognize its json?

Comment: Yes I saw that, but the ajax request doesn't affect the data passed to `format`. Try to log your `result` in `success`

Comment: The result inside success returns Object {data: Array[2]}

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the response is still in string format. You can add JSON.parse to convert it to an object and then be able too access the `data` property.

Try modifying your function like this to see if it fixes the problem.

```
function format(notes) {
   console.log(notes); //this displays the json
   // The following converts the response to a javascript object
   // and catches the exception if the response is not valid JSON
   try {
      notes = JSON.parse(notes);
   } catch(e) {
      console.log('notes is not valid JSON: ' + e);
   }
   var object = notes.data;
   console.log(object);
   var i;
   for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
      var Result = object[i];
      var Answer = Result.Answer;
      console.log(Answer)
   }
}
```

Comment: As he said in comments : `The result inside success returns Object {data: Array[2]}`. If the response was a string, he will not get this with a console log but the string itself